# Linux soft lockup in multi-core with realtime task

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, scheduling

I'm not sure whether it is Linux kernel bug while I searched many documents and could not find any hint.
I am asking this question to check if anyone has met similar issue and how to solve this.

```
Environment: 
Linux Kernel: 2.6.34.10 
CPU: MIPS 64 (total 8 cores)
application running in user space`
```

There are strict response time requirement with application, so the application threads were set in SCHED_FIFO, and some key threads are affinity to dedicated CPU core, everything is fine in this case. Later someone found that CPU peak happen (e.g. 60%-80% in short peak) sometimes in some CPU cores. To solve this, kept CPU 0 and CPU 7 for Linux native application, and isolated CPU 1-6 for our applications by adding "isolcpus=1-6" in boot line, issue of CPU peak was solved, while it lead the following issue.

The following message will be printed in console after running some time and system hangup, not always but sporadically. (it might happen in multiple CPU cores)

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 61s! [swapper:0]
Modules linked in: hdml softdog cmt cmm pio clock linux_kernel_bde  linux_uk_proxy linux_bcm_core mpt2sas
Cpu 4
$ 0   : 0000000000000000 ffffffffc3600020 ffffffffc1000b00 c0000001006f0010
$ 4   : 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 000000005410f8e0 ffffffffbfff00fe
$ 8   : 000000000000001e ffffffffc15b3c80 0000000000000002 0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d
$12   : 0000000000000000 000000004000f800 0000000000000000 c000000100768000
$16   : ffffffffc36108e0 0000000000000010 ffffffffc35f0000 0000000000000000
$20   : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
$24   : 0000000000000007 ffffffffc103b3a0                                  
$28   : c0000001006f0000 c0000001006f3e38 0000000000000000 ffffffffc103d774
Hi    : 0000000000000000
Lo    : 003d0980b38a5000
epc   : ffffffffc1000b20 r4k_wait+0x20/0x40
    Not tainted
ra    : ffffffffc103d774 cpu_idle+0xbc/0xc8
Status: 5410f8e3    KX SX UX KERNEL EXL IE 
Cause : 40808000
```

looked at the callback trace, the thread was always pending on conditional variable wait, the pseudo wait/signal fnction is as following

```
int xxx_ipc_wait(int target)    
{
struct timespec to;

.... /* other code */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &to);
timespec_add_ns(&to, 1000000);
pthread_mutex_lock(&ipc_queue_mutex[target]);
ret = pthread_cond_timedwait (&ipc_queue_cond[target], &ipc_queue_mutex[target], &to);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ipc_queue_mutex[target]);

return ret;
}

void xxx_ipc_signal_atonce(int target)
{
... 
pthread_mutex_lock(&ipc_queue_mutex[target]);
pthread_cond_signal(&ipc_queue_cond[target]);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ipc_queue_mutex[target]);
}
```

those waits should wakeup anyhow because it is timeout conditional variable. Even created a dedicated Linux thread to signal those conditional variable timely, e.g. every 5 seconds, issue still there.

checked the kernel log with "dmesg" and didn't found any valuable log. when enabled the kernel debug and check the kernel log /proc/sched_debug, there are strange information as following.

```
cpu#1   /* it is a normal CPU core */
  .nr_running                    : 1
  .load                          : 0
  .nr_switches                   : 1892378
  .nr_load_updates               : 167378
  .nr_uninterruptible            : 0
  .next_balance                  : 4295.060682
  .curr->pid                     : 235  /* it point to the runnable tasks */
            task   PID         tree-key  switches  prio     exec-runtime         sum-exec        sum-sleep
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R         aaTask   235         0.000000       157    49                0               0         

cpu#4
  .nr_running                    : 1  /* okay */
  .load                          : 0
  .nr_switches                   : 2120455  /* this value changes from time to time */
  .nr_load_updates               : 185729
  .nr_uninterruptible            : 0
  .next_balance                  : 4295.076207
  .curr->pid                     : 0   /* why this is ZERO since it has runable task */
  .clock                         : 746624.000000
  .cpu_load[0]                   : 0
  .cpu_load[1]                   : 0
  .cpu_load[2]                   : 0
  .cpu_load[3]                   : 0
  .cpu_load[4]                   : 0
cfs_rq[4]:/
  .exec_clock                    : 0.000000
  .MIN_vruntime                  : 0.000001
  .min_vruntime                  : 14.951424
  .max_vruntime                  : 0.000001
  .spread                        : 0.000000
  .spread0                       : -6833.777140
  .nr_running                    : 0
  .load                          : 0
  .nr_spread_over                : 0
  .shares                        : 0
 rt_rq[4]:/
  .rt_nr_running                 : 1
  .rt_throttled                  : 1
  .rt_time                       : 900.000000
  .rt_runtime                    : 897.915785

runnable tasks:
            task   PID         tree-key  switches  prio     exec-runtime         sum-exec        sum-sleep
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       bbbb_appl   299         6.664495   1059441    49               0               0               0.000000               0.000000               0.000000 /
```

I don't know why Linux system work like this, and finally, I changed the task priority from SCHED_FIFO to SCHED_OTHER, and this issue didn't happen after months' running. since CPU core is isolated, so system's behavior is similar between SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_OTHER, also SCHED_OTHER is more widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App waiting on a condition/mutex forever might be a sign of priority inversion, unless it's using priority inheritance enabled synchronization primitives.

In the FIFO realtime scheduling mode the thread has CPU until it voluntarily gives it up. Which is quite different from the preemptive multitasking most software is written for.

Unless your software explicitly has REALTIME_FIFO in the configuration requirements, I would not spend time and rather stick with RR and/or CPU pinning/isolation.

Comment: this product is originated from embedded RTOS, that why set to real-time at beginning. I fully agree with you that with CPU isolation and affinity/pinning, our test also showed that application will not interrupted by other tasks and response time is committed.

Comment: I added PI paragraph to my answer. Are you able to confirm if your app is using PI-enabled synchronization when synchronizing threads of different priority?

Comment: actually there is only one application thread running on the CPU core that got stuck, while there are some kernel threads running on each CPU cores even it is isolated, e.g. file system thread. What confusing me is that there was runnable thread available in CPU core 4 according to the log (here I believe runnable means it was not pending, it was waken up), but why .curr->pid is 0?